# How to pass variable template to extend template as a parameter in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

i have a variables declared in yaml templates like

```
# File: vars.yml
variables:
- name: firstvar
  value:'first var value'
- name: secondvar
  value:'second var value'
```

and in pipeline i'm using extend template

```
trigger:
- none

extends:
  template: resource-template.yml
  paramters:
    uservariablestemplate: <i want to pass above variable yaml template here>
```

because my extend template using other variables so this user defined variables should be used in there

```
    # File: resource-template.yml
   parameters:
   - name: uservariablestemplate
     type: string
     default: none

    resources:
      repositories:
      - repository: samplerepo
        type: git
        name: myproject/myrepo
    
    variables:
    - template: centralvariables.yml@samplerepo
    - template: <i want to use variable template from user here>
    
    steps:
     - script: echo "Testing resource template"
```

Any help would be appreciated. or any other workaround to achieve this.

Comment: so what happens if you just pass it to the variables?

Answer (score 3):

You can just pass the variable template file name to the parameters. For below example:

```
trigger:
- none

extends:
  template: resource-template.yml
  paramters:
    uservariablestemplate: vars.yml
```

Then in the template `resource-template.yml`, retrieve the variable template using `${{parameters.uservariablestemplate}}`. See below example:

```
   parameters:
   - name: uservariablestemplate
     type: string
     default: none

   resources:
     repositories:
     - repository: samplerepo
       type: git
       name: myproject/myrepo
    
   variables:
   - template: centralvariables.yml@samplerepo
   - template: ${{parameters.uservariablestemplate}}
    
   steps:
    - script: echo "Testing resource template"
```

If the variable template file resides in another repo. You need to define the repo in the repo resources section. For below example:

```
   parameters:
   - name: uservariablestemplate
     type: string
     default: none

   resources:
     repositories:
     - repository: samplerepo
       type: git
       name: myproject/myrepo
     
     - repository: variableRepo
       type: git
       name: myVariableRepo
    
   variables:
   - template: centralvariables.yml@samplerepo
   - template: ${{parameters.uservariablestemplate}}@variableRepo
    
   steps:
    - script: echo "Testing resource template"
```

Update:

To dynamically set the repo name, you can try using [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script). See below: Define a runtime parameter `repo`:

```
trigger: none

parameters:
- name: repo
  type: string
  default: none

extends:
  template: resource-template.yml
  parameters:
    uservariablestemplate: vars.yml
```

Then you can refer to the repo by `${{parameters.repo}}` in the following yaml.

When you run your pipeline. You will be able to set the repo name:

[image]

Comment: the problem is resources section in extend template where we have to define the user repo as a resource, which is not scalable, Our extend templates will be used by several teams.  we cannot parameter repo name and initialize repo dynamically which sucks. the only option i see is variable groups where we wont get commit history of variables.

Comment: I think you can check out the runtime parameters, which will allow you to dynamic set the repo name when you run the pipeline. Check above update

Comment: Hi @Sanjeev Did you check out above update, how did it go with the runtime parameters?